# Hide parent when child got display none

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create some jQuery that hide the parent when a child element got display none as html.

My html looks like this:

```
<li class="formListBlock payment_mollie_applepay paymentchecked">
    <label for="p_method_mollie_applepay" style="display: none;"></label>
</li>
```

Tried:

```
<script>
if $("label[for='p_method_mollie_applepay']").not(":visible"){  
$(this).parent().hide();
}   
</script>
```

So now I want to hide the `<li>` element with a display none, when the label got the class `display: none;`

How can I achieve this the best way?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @KévinBibollet Sorry, added my code.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can use `:has()` to filter the `li` elements to retrieve only those containing hidden `label` elements, before you `hide()` or `remove()` them.

```js
$('li:has(label:hidden)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="formListBlock payment_mollie_applepay paymentchecked">
    <label for="p_method_mollie_applepay" style="display: none;">Hidden</label>
  </li>
  <li class="formListBlock payment_mollie_applepay paymentchecked">
    <label for="p_method_mollie_applepay">Visible</label>
  </li>
  <li class="formListBlock payment_mollie_applepay paymentchecked">
    <label for="p_method_mollie_applepay" style="display: none;">Hidden</label>
  </li>
  <li class="formListBlock payment_mollie_applepay paymentchecked">
    <label for="p_method_mollie_applepay">Visible</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```